# How make a texture opaque at the center of my object and transparent at extremities for lowpoly clouds?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

How make a texture opaque at the center of my object and transparent at extremities for lowpoly clouds?

[image]

As you can see in the picture, clouds are completely transparent. What can I add in the node editor? Don't mind the plane.

[image]

Comment: The clouds are particles, correct? What object did you use to make them, a UV sphere?

Comment: yes exactly, i subdivided it and used sculpture mode (for the UV sphere)